# how to expose start/stop/status features for all java batchs running in a Web Server

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole, jsr352

My straight question is: let's say I have 10 wars deployed to my server. Inside of each one there is a simple job either coded with Spring Batch or JSR352 implementations. Then I want to start, check the status and stop them manually? What from an enterprise server would provide me that ability? For instance, let's say I have 10 batchs deployed to the same server (I use Websphere 8.5.5 ND with JDK 7 but you can have anyone in your mind). Five batchs are JSR-352 and others five are Spring Batch. I want to provide a single page for final user where he/she can start the server, see if it is running and then stop it while it is running (It is beyond this question talk about the front end side. It can be as simple a butom for start, another for stop and just refresh the page to see the current status). The question is focused in how to expose start/stop/status ability about Batchs deployed to a Web Server.

Let me explain a bit deeper. I have worked for the last 6 months in order to create few jobs with Spring Batch. For some reason, I can't start it straigh from unix shell or JCL in my company. In pratical terms it means I can't use a script starting it  with command lines. I must use inside of our Websphere 8.5.5 ND. There is an amazing application named Spring Batch Admin that would fit my necessity but, to make short, I can't use it here.

It is beyond this question compare Spring Batch with JSR 352. For my question I really don't care which one I will use as long as I can offer someway for a monitor/operator/user to see in a web page someway to start/stop/check status. So if you can answer only for JSR 352 or only for Spring Batch it will be perfect. Obviously a bit better if there is some generic way to cover both.

I guess, not sure, that there might be someway to use JMX or JConsole feature to do something similar to what Spring Batch Admin does but I don't have the north and it is hard for me to start without a scratch direction. I am sure it is perfectly possible otherwise it wouldn't exist an application named Spring Batch Admin offering that (I have used it very well but I can't make it works in production for local reasons).

I think in JMX because I understand JMX can register beans and expose it and I think in JConsole from the Java used for my server because it shows what is going on with the same JVM used for that server.

Readers that got interested in this question but didn't understand what I mean by JSR 352 or Spring Batch Admin may get interested in this two links:

JSR352 in Websphere ND
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=tss1wp102544&aid=1

Spring Batch Admin
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-batch-admin-tutorial/

Very interested movie convering both implementations:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKs4yPs-5yU

I would like to put in spot light that answer that try to compare Spring Batch with JSR352 I will downgrade the answer. It is very far away from my question and motivation.

Comment: There is no support in WebSphere Application Server traditional 8.5.5 for JSR 352 (there is only the proprietary "WebSphere Compute Grid" Java batch support).  The link you noted: "JSR352 in Websphere ND" actually describes the JSR 352 support in WebSphere Liberty.      Would Liberty be an option for your use case?

Comment: Computer Grid seems to fit perfectly what I need. If I understood right, I can give up from Spring Batch and use WAS Computer Grid in order to have my java jobs inside of Websphere. My problem is that I can't isntall jobs straight to Unix but I am allowed to add any EAR in WAS ND. That said, you may understand why I am interested to find someway to have my java jobs inside of WAS and provide some front end for start/stop/status mantenince. Please, can you explain how do I figure out if I have WAS Computer Grid alread installed? Any hello world example deployed to WAS ND will be appreciated.

Comment: There's a somewhat aged intro to Compute Grid here:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0801_vignola/0801_vignola.html.  And more information about Compute Grid in general here:  https://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP101783.  
Compute Grid ceased to be a separate product after V8.0 and is included automatically as part of the WebSphere V8.5 product so it isn't something you need to buy anymore.
All that said...IBM's strategic direction for Java Batch is JSR-352 and not Compute Grid which is a proprietary Java Batch implementation.

Comment: DFollis, kindly, do you know any IBM document informing "IBM's strategic direction for Java Batch is JSR-352 and not Compute Grid"?